# UISearchBar - Keyboard NOT displaying when touched

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar

The keyboard is not being displayed when I touch the UISearchBar in my iphone app.  Do I have to use something like [searchBar becomeFirstResponder] in touchesBegan?

I have the searchBarShouldBeginEditing returning YES.

I have tried using [seachBar becomeFirstResponder] and my delegate gets called as I expect.  I see there is a UISearchDisplayController but I thought perhaps a UISearchBar was easy enough to implement.

My custom controller class is a subclass of UIViewController.

```
UIImageView *topImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                        [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                         [myBundle pathForResource:@"top_header"  
  ofType:@"png"inDirectory:@"Images/facebook_friend"]]];

CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 310) 
       style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.bounces = YES;

UIImageView *bottomImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                         [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
                          [myBundle pathForResource:@"bottom_background" ofType:@"png" 
                inDirectory:@"Images/facebook_friend"]]];
bottomImage.center = CGPointMake(bottomImage.center.x, 480-bottomImage.frame.size.height);
// so that we can push a button inside it


self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70,320,0)];
[searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search"];
[searchBar setDelegate:self];


tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = dataSource;
[tableView reloadData];

UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 76, 43)];
backButton.center = CGPointMake(210, 40);
[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/facebook_friend/back-button.png"]
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backClick:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// spinner to show we're loading
self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,100,50,50)];
[spinner setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[tableView addSubview:spinner];

// top search section
[myView addSubview:topImage];
[topImage addSubview:searchBar];

// friend list
[myView addSubview:tableView];

// bottom button section
[bottomImage addSubview:backButton];
[bottomImage addSubview:postButton];
[myView addSubview:bottomImage];

[topImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[bottomImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[myView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

self.view = myView;
```

Edit: Sun 9:50am

If I take all the subviews out and just add myView with the searchBar, I only see touch events for myView.   However if I just set

```
self.view=searchBar
```

then touching the search bar brings up the keyboard.  Here is a very small example:

```
CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70,320,0)];
[searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search"];

[myView addSubview:searchBar];
self.view = myView;
```

Comment: This is really weird bug as if you just place searchbar and don't define delegate or any method then after it shows keyboard on tap of searchbar text field. Are you sure you are not doing something unusual stuff ? Can you post something to guess ? XIB Screenshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of my UISearchBar was 0 and this is why it wasn't displaying the keyboard when I clicked.